# How to get a Java request response from PHP page in an array

Tags: java, php, android-studio

I am new to Java... But I have tried to achieve this in JS successfully, but I don't know how to do same in Java.

### Question

I am building an android app in Android Studio, and I have this code that sends a POST request to a PHP page in my local server.

```
String url = "http://localhost/inc/signUp.php";
StringRequest rqst = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        //get my response in an Array
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    }
});
```

And in my `signUp.php` I am outputting the response `JSON_ENCODE`

```
$data = array('state', 'value');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Now on the Java code, I want to get the response in an array but I don't know how to do that

Comment: If you can read the raw response inside the `onResponse` method you can decode it using a library like Gson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... I got this code, and it works for me

```
String url = "http://localhost/inc/signUp.php";
StringRequest rqst = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        //get my response in an Array
        try{
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
        } catch (JSONExeption e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    }
});
```